# In need of a script to detect when a cell's numeric value has changed, and change the row colour

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm currently creating a stock inventory system using Google Sheets, and I've ran in to an issue at the final hurdle. I'm using conditional formatting to adjust colours of rows etc... when a certain drop down option has been selected from the "Updated On Cart?" column, however I need a script (because this won't be possible using just conditional formatting) to detect when the "QTY" cell has changed / is updated from its current value (to anything, not just a specific value).

I've gone through what feels like 25 pages of Google, and countless posts on StackOverflow, to no avail.

Here's an image of the system as it is at the moment.

[Image of stock sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbXAK.png)

So basically when a user changes the quantity of a stock item, the row should change colour.

If anyone knows of a script I can use, or can point me in the right direction of a solution for Google Spreadsheet that would be great.

Comment: Do you want an Excel solution, or Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: A Google Spreadsheet solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some script could help:

```
function onEdit(t) {

var workSheetName = 'Sheet1'; // change sheet name to yours
var targetRangeAddress = 'E2:E'; // change if needed

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sn = ss.getName();

if (sn == workSheetName) {
  var myr = ss.getRange(targetRangeAddress);
  var tr = t.range;
  if (t.oldValue != tr.getValue() && t.oldValue != undefined) {
  if (RangeIntersect(tr, myr)) {
      var cr = ss.getRange(tr.getRow(),1,1,ss.getLastColumn());
      cr.setBackgroundRGB(200, 200, 200); // change if needed
    }
  }
}
}


function RangeIntersect(R1, R2) {

  var LR1 = R1.getLastRow();
  var Ro2 = R2.getRow();
  if (LR1 < Ro2) return false;


  var LR2 = R2.getLastRow();
  var Ro1 = R1.getRow();
  if (LR2 < Ro1) return false;

  var LC1 = R1.getLastColumn();
  var C2 = R2.getColumn();
  if (LC1 < C2) return false;

  var LC2 = R2.getLastColumn();
  var C1 = R1.getColumn();
  if (LC2 < C1) return false;

return true;

}
```

---

Or may be just copy column (E:E) values to the next to it coulmn (F:F) and set Conditional Formatting rule for *all table range* with your formula:  `=$E2<>$F2`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this only seems to be highlighting the current cell instead of the row. What do I need to modify to highlight the row instead?

Comment: Please, try it now. That's pretty easy. I've just edited target range in script where to change colour. I've also changed formula for Data validstion, and it should work too.

Comment: Thanks again, but unfortunately the column is being highlighted instead of the row. I'm not sure what the lower section of the code is doing, so can't troubleshoot it myself.

Comment: sorry, I've misandestood you, It was my inattention. Changed the code again :)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help Max! Much appreciated. I've marked your original answer as the accepted one :)

Comment: Sorry, ran in to an issue (not with your code, but due to some modifications in how I'm laying out the stock sheet). I now have separate sheets for different sections of stock, however I don't know how to get the script to run across the whole document and not just one sheet. Any thoughts?

Comment: To make script work on any sheet in a workbook: delete lines: 1. `var workSheetName = 'Sheet1';`  , 2.  `if (sn == workSheetName) {` , 3. `}` before `function RangeIntersect...`. This will remove condition on sheetname.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply! :) All working now.